# Как сделать "рассылку" по серверу discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

У меня есть вопрос по разработке бота. Заключается он в следущем:
Как можно сделать рассылку по всем каналам сервера? Т. е. бот отправит на все каналы определенное сообщение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте это, переберая каналы, вот так:

```py
@bot.command()
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for server in bot.servers:
        for channel in server.channels:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

В цикле можете прописать свою функцию, кроме отправки сообщений.

Comment: Спасибо! Во второй раз мне помогаете!

Comment: Собственно, я так со всеми. Не за что)